# Running nosetest corrupts putty session

Tags: python, putty, tmux, nose

When I run `nosetests` in my `putty` session, the command prompts stops working. For example, what ever key I type turns into `)`

The only way I found so far to recover is to restart the session.

The command I run is:

```
nosetests -v --with-xunitmp -m "(?:\b|_)[Tt]est" --xunitmp-file nosetests.xml  --processes=10 --process-timeout=600
```

I use nosetests `1.3.7` and python `3.5.1`

#### Edit:

I've narrowed it down a bit.

- It is happening outside of tmux (in a putty session)
- It is happening because I start other processes from my python tests

Here's an example:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from subprocess import Popen
import time

class MyTest(TestCase):
    def test_this(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_with_process(self):

        process = Popen(['watch', 'ls'])
        time.sleep(1)
        if process.poll() is None:
            process.kill()
```

#### Edit 2:

It seems like redirecting the subprocess to `/dev/null` fixes the issue:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from subprocess import Popen, DEVNULL
import time

class MyTest(TestCase):
    def test_this(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_with_process(self):

        process = Popen(['watch', 'ls'],
                stdout=DEVNULL,
                stderr=DEVNULL,
                stdin=DEVNULL)
        time.sleep(1)
        if process.poll() is not None:
            print("KILLING")
            process.kill()
            process.communicate()
```

It resolves the issue, I'd like to understand why this is happening...

Comment: Does this happen when you run in a terminal without tmux? Does this happen with a different set of tests for nosetests? Do you have a [Minimum Viable Concrete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @jeremysprofile, I've edited my answer. It does happen without tmux as well. Also I've got and easy to reproduce example and I found a solution, but  I don't understand why the problem occurs.